# Pagination on Wp-Property not working

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is using Wp-Property and the pagination isn't working, can anyone help fix this please. Please see below the pagination part from the function page.

```
<?php if($use_pagination) { ?>
    if(!wpp_pagination_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?>) {
      jQuery("#wpp_shortcode_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?> .wpp_pagination_slider_wrapper").each(function() {
        var this_parent = this;
        /* Slider */
        jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider', this).slider({
          value:1,
          min: 1,
          max: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
          step: 1,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            /* Update page counter - we do it here because we want it to be instant */
            jQuery("#wpp_shortcode_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?> .wpp_current_page_count").text(ui.value);
            jQuery("#wpp_shortcode_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?> .wpp_pagination_slider .slider_page_info .val").text(ui.value);
          },
          stop: function(event, ui) {
            wpp_query_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?> = changeAddressValue(ui.value, wpp_query_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?>);
          }

        });

        /* Fix slider width based on button width */
        var slider_width = (jQuery(this_parent).width() - jQuery(".wpp_pagination_back", this_parent).outerWidth() - jQuery(".wpp_pagination_forward", this_parent).outerWidth() - 30);
        jQuery(".wpp_pagination_slider", this_parent).css('width', slider_width);

        jQuery('.wpp_pagination_slider .ui-slider-handle', this).append('<div class="slider_page_info"><div class="val">1</div><div class="arrow"></div></div>');

      });
      wpp_pagination_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?> = true;
    }
    <?php } ?>
  });
</script>
<?php
$js_result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start(); ?>
<div class="properties_pagination <?php echo $settings['class']; ?> wpp_slider_pagination" id="properties_pagination_<?php echo $unique_hash; ?>">
  <div class="wpp_pagination_slider_status">

      <?php
      if(function_exists('WPPFL_getNumberOfFavorites')) {
          $num_of_favorites = WPPFL_getNumberOfFavorites();
      } else{
          $num_of_favorites = 0;
      }

      $currentTemplate = "";
      if (isset($wpp_query['template'])) {
        $currentTemplate = $wpp_query['template'];
      }
      ?>
      <?php if ($currentTemplate==TEMPLATEPATH . "/list-my-property-content.php") { ?>
          <div class="wppcs-sub-menu">
              <?php global $post;
              $post_name = $post->post_name; ?>
              <?php $class='class="active"'; ?>
              <ul>
                  <li <?php if($post_name == 'list-my-property') { echo $class; } ?>>
                      <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/list-my-property/">
                          View Listed Properties
                      </a>
                  </li>
                  <li <?php if($post_name == 'add-new-property') { echo $class; } ?>>
                      <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/list-my-property/add-new-property/">
                          Add New Property
                      </a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      <?php } else { ?>
          <ul class="top_part">
              <li><a>Search results</a></li>
              <li class="favor"><a href="/favourite-properties">My Favourites(<span class="number_of_favorites"><?php echo $num_of_favorites; ?></span>)</a></li>
          </ul>
      <?php } ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <?php if($use_pagination) { ?>
  <div class="wpp_pagination_slider_wrapper">
    <div class="wpp_page_numbers_block">
        <span class="numbers-title">Pages</span>
        <?php
        if ($pages < 10) {
            for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
                echo '<span class="page_numbers" data-value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</span>';
            }
        } else {
            for($i=1; $i<=$pages; $i++) {
                if (($i < 4) || ($i>$pages-3)) {
                    echo '<span class="page_numbers" data-value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</span>';
                }
                if ($i==4) {
                    echo '<span class="middle-pages"><span class="dotted-separator">...</span></span>';
                }
            }
        }?>
    </div>
    <div class="wpp_pagination_back wpp_pagination_button"><?php _e('Prev', 'wpp'); ?></div>
    <div class="wpp_pagination_forward wpp_pagination_button"><?php _e('Next', 'wpp'); ?></div>
    <div class="wpp_pagination_slider"></div>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
<div class="ajax_loader"></div>
<?php
$html_result = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Thank you in anticaption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing which can cause your issue is some of third party plugins or your theme. So try firstly to deactivate third party plugins and switch theme to default one to be sure that issue doesn't relate to any of them.
Such request you can also send here
https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-property
or on our site
https://usabilitydynamics.com/contact-us/

Regards.
Usability Dynamics Support